# I need to make a program that makes a rectangle that moves and when it reaches the end of the screen in goes to the next line in pygame

Tags: pygame

question:
this is my code. It is supposed to make a rectangle automatically move and when it reached the end of the screen it has to go the next row. I am able to make it move 1 row but no more than that! here is my code:

```
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init
white = (255,255,255)
x = 0
y = 0
s = 0
a = 25
d = 500
black = (0,0,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("AppliedShapes")
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,(x,y,50,50),0)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    x += a
    if x == 500:
        for x in range(1,10,1):
            x = 0
            y = s + a
   
    pygame.display.update()
```

PLEASE!
if you know how. and use the same methods that i did if you could

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do, is to [have a read](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) of the documentation about PyGame Rectangles.  These are a beautiful piece of library code, and one of the absolute core items in PyGame.  They make lots of operations much simpler, and easier.

[image: video demo]

So now you know about rectangles, let's make one:

```
move_rect = pygame.Rect( 5, 0, 50, 50 )  # define a Rect
```

So instead of keeping a bunch of co-ordinates and sizes in separate variables, we now just have a `move_rect`.  We can re-position this rectangle in a few different ways, but one very handy function is `move_ip()` == Move In Place.  You give it a pair of numbers, and it adjusts the rectangle's position incrementally by these amounts.

We need to know beforehand how much to move the rectangle each frame.  I think variables named `move_x` and `move_y` are more easily understood than `s`, `a`, and `d`, so let's go with those:

```
# rectangle that moves
move_rect = pygame.Rect( 5, 0, 50, 50 )  # define a Rect
move_x    = 5                            # pixels movement
move_y    = 2 + move_rect.height         # pixels movement
```

So you can see we're moving 5 pixels horizontally, and 2 pixels *plus* the height of the rectangle, vertically.

But how do we know when the rectangle hit's the screen edge?  Well the window is `500` pixels square, so this is just "when at 500".  But I don't want to pepper the code with lots of 500s, just for you to tell me it's now changed to 550 after I'm finished.  So we'll put the screen dimensions into variables too:

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_HEIGHT= 500
...
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
```

Then we can test the rectangles position against `SCREEN_WIDTH`, etc.

```
# Has the rectangle touched the side of the screen?
if ( move_rect.left <= 0 or move_rect.right >= SCREEN_WIDTH-1 ):
    # do something
```

The PyGame `Rect` has a whole bunch of useful properties: `left`, `top`, `right`, `center` (note US-english spelling), `width` ... these make checking rectangle positions very simple.

```
if ( move_rect.left <= 0 ):  # is the rect's left-side at the screen edge?

if ( move_rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT ):  # or off the bottom?
```

Using the Rect, we can easily detect when we've touched the screen edge.  So then what?  Well we change direction.  That means if we were going `+5` pixels each time to move right, now we can go `-5` pixels to achieve a left.  Each time we move down, just invert the direction amount.  This can be done by multiplying by `-1` (because `5 x -1 => -5` and `-5 x -1 => 5` (just in case you weren't sure)).  Thus each time we hit the side, we multiply `move_x` by `-1`. Easy.

The downward movement is pretty much the same, except when we hit the bottom of the screen, we go back to the top.

```
import time
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Constants
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_HEIGHT= 500
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

# Pygame initialisation
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AppliedShapes")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# rectangle that moves
move_rect = pygame.Rect( 5, 0, 50, 50 )  # define a Rect
move_x    = 5                            # pixels movement
move_y    = 2 + move_rect.height         # pixels movement

while True:
    # User input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    # Screen re-painting
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,white, move_rect ,0)

    # Move the rectangle, reverse direction at the sides
    if ( move_rect.left <= 0 or move_rect.right >= SCREEN_WIDTH-1 ):
        # Hit the sides: move down, change direction
        move_x *= -1           # change direction
        move_rect.move_ip( move_x, move_y )
    elif ( move_rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT-1 ):
        # Hit the bottom: move back to 0,0, continue right
        move_x = abs( move_x )  # re-start going right
        move_rect.topleft = ( move_x, 0 )
    else:
        # Didn't hit anything, just continue horizontally
        move_rect.move_ip( move_x, 0 )

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60) # limit FPS to 60
```